# Is it possible to merge two health sources without losing data?

Tags: ios, health.app

I am using the Health app on iOS 10.3.2 (14F5089a) with 2 Apple Watches paired. However, there are more than 2 watches listed in the Sources tab. I know that only one listing contains the data for one Apple Watch, but the other Apple Watch has 4 listings with only one marked as 'still paired'.

Is there a way I can merge the 4 listings with the least amount of data loss possible?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't delete any Apple Watch from the sources tab if you care about your health records.

You can't merge these entries. **If you need to remove an Apple Watch, do. so using the Watch.app on your iPhone.**

I have multiple entries for my Apple Watches as well listed in my sources:

[image: apple health > sources tab]